# Model popup Extender issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using a model popup extender in my page. I have created some rule. If that rule is true, then show model popup extender otherwise hide it.I am using  the below code to display model popub extender.

```
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modelPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="Lnk_1"
            PopupControlID="pan_addEdit" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pan_addEdit" runat="server" CssClass="pnl">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Lnk_1" runat="server" OnClick="btn_generate_Click" Visible="true"></asp:LinkButton>
            <table border="0" width="800px" height="350px">
            .......
```

My problem is when the rule condition is false, it just shows and disappears in a fraction of second. How can i reduce it.

Comment: Does rule may be evaluated on client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your ModalPopupExtender's **TargetID** is your `LinkButton Id`, irrespective of the RULE, it will always show even before that RULE is checked.
The solution is to add a `HiddenField` and pass its ID as **TargetID** to ModalPopupExtender. This way you can check the RULE when LinkBUtton is clicked and use **`ModalPopupExtender.Show()`** to show the popup.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnpop" runat="server" />

<asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modelPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="hdnpop"
            PopupControlID="pan_addEdit" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In LinkButton event,

```
if(RULE)
{//Do something
    modelPopupExtender1.Show()
}
else
{
   //Do something else an dont Show()
}
```